# ¿Cómo añadir valores integer a un vector puntero integer?

Tags: c++, heap

Estoy tratando de ingresar valores a un vector puntero de integers de pero estoy teniendo problemas con el acceso a la memoria (0xC0000005 error).

```
    std::vector<int>* vectorDeNumeros;
    vectorDeNumeros->push_back(13);
```

En este ejemplo, estoy tratando de añadir un valor integer al vector puntero de integer, pero falla en hacerlo y no sé que hacer para poder ingresarle valores no-puntero de tipo integer a este vector.

Este es el código de salida.

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Please translate your question, this site is Stackoverflow in spanish.

Comment: Ya está traducido.

Comment: Y a donde apunta ese puntero? Si solo declaras un puntero de esa manera no apunta a ningún lado, y por eso te da el error. Tienes que asignar memoria valida a la que apute.

Comment: No olvides traducir el título :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí declaras un puntero a un objeto de tipo `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int>* vectorDeNumeros;
```

Y seguidamente accedes al objeto referenciado por el puntero:

```
vectorDeNumeros->push_back(13);
```

Peeero en ningún momento has inicializado el puntero para que apunte a un objeto válido:

```
vectorDeNumeros = new std::vector<int>();
```

Claro que lo mismo sucede que te estás liando y realmente no necesitas el puntero:

```
std::vector<int> vectorDePunteros;
vectorDePuneros.push_back(13);
```

Esta otra opción **sí** funciona porque ahora `vectorDePunteros` no es un puntero sino un objeto, y los objetos **siempre** invocan un constructor cuando se declaran